# Optimize/Memoize a big reducer using React useReducer

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-context

I am building a game using React and I have a very big "GameState" context that store all the game data, and provide functions to interact with it.

I only used React Context, using a reducer with more than 20 cases.

The problem is : The game becoming more and more complex, it slows down over the time and becomes almost unplayable after 1 hour. So I feel the need to optimize it but I'm not sure how to do it.

My first thought was to provide the state and dispatch in two different contexts. This can help but I really doubt it will be enough.

My second idea is to memoize the reducer, but I feel like it doesn't make sense to memoize it with the full state as dependency.

**So my question is : How do you optimize and memoize a big reducer ?**

Should I stop using useReducer, and use useState/useCallback instead so I have more control over the dependencies of each function that interact with the state ? Or is there another way I didn't think of ?

---

*Here is a concrete example : [GameContext.tsx](https://github.com/maxthizeau/OnePieceClicker/blob/master/src/lib/hooks/GameContext.tsx)

Line 164 : gameReducer() function

Line 751 : GameProvider() Context Provider function*